# Overhead of GCP Monitoring Agent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

Is there any document for the Overhead or resource usage of the [GCP Monitoring Agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/monitoring)?

I'm looking for a solution that needs less than 100MB of RAM